# How to dynamically create a method with a variable number of parameters stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, function, binding, delegation, arity

In order to set up a Socket.IO client, I have a bunch of methods looking like this:

```js
myobject.prototype.A = function (callback) {
    this.foo('a', null, callback);
}

myobject.prototype.B = function (bar, callback) {
    this.foo('b', { bar }, callback);
}

myobject.prototype.C = function (baz, qux, callback) {
    this.foo('c', { baz, qux }, callback);
}
```

The content of `this.foo` is unimportant, but it takes 3 parameters: a string, an object built from the calling method parameters, and a callback method.

I'd like to have the methods set up in a single place. I'd like to have something looking like this:

```js
// I'm not sure what form the args should take
const methods = {
  A: { socketName: 'a', args: [ ] },
  B: { socketName: 'b', args: [ 'bar' ] },
  C: { socketName: 'c', args: [ 'baz', 'qux' ] }
};

for (let m in methods) {
    const mData = methods[m];
    this.prototype[m] = function (what_do_I_put_here_?, callback) {
        // how do I form "otherArgs" ?
        this.foo(mData.socketName, otherArgs, callback);
    }
}
```

I think I'll have to look to destructuring assignments but I'm not sure how to use them in this case.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done JS, but are you looking for `function (x, ...args)`?

Comment: Are the arguments *static*? Are they always the string `'y'` or the strings `'y'` and `'z'`?

Comment: It is unclear what `this.foo('c', x, { y, z });` actually does.  Does it really create an object with the keys `y` and `z`? Did you really mean that it does this `this.foo('c', x, { y: y, z: z });`?

Comment: And what exactly does `triggerCallback` do? It is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I have amended my question in the hope to be more clear.

@VLAZ : the arguments vary so they can be called whatever. My question now reflects this.

@t.niese : yes the object is `{ y: y, z: z }` but in my case `{ y, z }` is identical.

I have removed the reference to `triggerCallback` as it's already implemented and works. It was just to make the point that I was already using such a loop for an adjacent purpose.

Comment: Then I'm not really sure why you have the `args` in that object. Doesn't seem to be used or serve anything useful.

Comment: Just saw that you added `callback` while I was writing the answer, that for sure would add some additional work. I right now don't have time to change my answer, but it would just need some additional work on the `args` argument (use the last element of `args` as callback)

Comment: `for (let m of methods)` I don't think `methods` would be iterable in your example.  You probably meant `for (let m in methods)`

Comment: @VLAZ : I have no idea how to write what I need, that's my question.
@Wyck : I have added them, and fixed the for in.
@t.niese : the `foo` method is internal, I can pass the callback as first argument. I'll check out your answer, thanks!

Comment: @thomasb ... The OP might have a look at a late provided answer which implements [a single function that handles any parameter configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77360559/2627243), including the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that utilizing closures and an array function:

```js
"use strict"
class Test {

  createDynFoo(name, propertyNames = []) {
    // return an arrow function (ensures that this is still the obj)
    return (x, ...args) => {
      let obj = null; // set obj to null as default
      if (args.length > 0) {
        // if we have additional aguments to x we create an obj
        obj = {};
        // map the additional arguments to the property names
        propertyNames.forEach((value, idx) => {
          obj[value] = args[idx]
        })
      }
      // call the actual foo function
      return this.foo(name, x, obj)
    }
  }

  foo(name, x, obj) {
    console.log(`${name} ${x}`)
    console.dir(obj);
  }
}

let test = new Test();


let tiggerForA = test.createDynFoo('a');
let tiggerForB = test.createDynFoo('b', ['y']);
let tiggerForC = test.createDynFoo('c', ['y', 'z']);

tiggerForA(1);
tiggerForB(1, 2);
tiggerForC(1, 2, 3);
```

If you really need it as member functions you could do:

```js
"use strict"
class Test {

  constructor() {
    this.A = this.createDynFoo('a');
    this.B = this.createDynFoo('b', ['y']);
    this.C = this.createDynFoo('c', ['y', 'z']);
  }


  createDynFoo(name, propertyNames = []) {
    // return an arrow function (ensures that this is still the obj)
    return (x, ...args) => {
      let obj = null; // set obj to null as default
      if (args.length > 0) {
        // if we have additional aguments to x we create an obj
        obj = {};
        // map the additional arguments to the property names
        propertyNames.forEach((value, idx) => {
          obj[value] = args[idx]
        })
      }
      // call the actual foo function
      return this.foo(name, x, obj)
    }
  }

  foo(name, x, obj) {
    console.log(`${name} ${x}`)
    console.dir(obj);
  }
}

let test = new Test();


test.A(1);
test.B(1, 2);
test.C(1, 2, 3);
```

If it is only about member functions you could get rid of the the arrow function like this:

```js
"use strict"



function createDynFunction(classObj, targetFunctionName, newFunctionName, name, propertyNames = []) {
  // create a new function and assigned it to the prototype of the class
  classObj.prototype[newFunctionName] = function(x, ...args) {
    let obj = null; // set obj to null as default
    if (args.length > 0) {
      // if we have additional aguments to x we create an obj
      obj = {};
      // map the additional arguments to the property names
      propertyNames.forEach((value, idx) => {
        obj[value] = args[idx]
      })
    }
    // call the actual foo function
    return this[targetFunctionName](name, x, obj)
  }
}

class Test {
  foo(name, x, obj) {
    console.log(`${name} ${x}`)
    console.dir(obj);
  }
}

createDynFunction(Test, 'foo', 'A', 'a');
createDynFunction(Test, 'foo', 'B', 'b', ['y']);
createDynFunction(Test, 'foo', 'C', 'c', ['y', 'z']);

let test = new Test();

test.A(1);
test.B(1, 2);
test.C(1, 2, 3);
```

As I don't know the exact use case, it is hard to come up with a solution that exactly matches the needs. But based on the shown code, you should get an idea how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const toObj = (keys, values) =>
  keys.length === 0
    ? null
    : _.zipObject(keys, values); 

function wrap(fn, name, keys) {
  return function(...args) {
    const callback = args.pop();
    const obj = toObj(keys, args);
    
    return fn.call(this, name, obj, callback);
  }
}

class Foo {
  foo(name, obj, callback) { 
    //calling a method to show that the value of `this` is forwarded in the call
    console.log(this.bar(name, obj, callback));
  }
  
  bar(name, obj, callback) {
    return `name: '${name}'; obj: '${JSON.stringify(obj)}', callback: '${callback}'`;
  }
}

const methods = {
  A: { socketName: 'a', args: [ ] },
  B: { socketName: 'b', args: [ 'bar' ] },
  C: { socketName: 'c', args: [ 'baz', 'qux' ] },
};

for (let m in methods) {
    const mData = methods[m];
    Foo.prototype[m] = wrap(Foo.prototype.foo, mData.socketName, mData.args);
}

const foo = new Foo();

foo.A(() => "this is A's callback");
foo.B("hello", () => "this is B's callback");
foo.C("hello", "world", () => "this is C's callback");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This utilises a higher order function that can wrap/decorate functions and enforce the needed parameters. [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) would also set the value of `this` when calling, thus if decorating a method it will use the value of `this` where it is called from [as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work):

```
/**
 * Wrap functions to ensure parameters are uniformly applied.
 *
 * @param {Function} fn - function to decorate
 * @param {string} name - first to be given to the function
 * @param {Array<string|number|Symbol>} keys - keys for the object which 
 * will become the second parameter of `fn`
 * 
 * @return {Function} function that will be called with variable number 
 * of arguments - the number of `keys` plus one callback. Forwards the 
 * value of `this` to the function.
 */
function wrap(fn, name, keys) {
  return function(...args) {
    const callback = args.pop();
    const obj = toObj(keys, args);
    
    return fn.call(this, name, obj, callback);
  }
}
```

There is the `toObj` which should take the keys and varargs, then produce an object out of them. I use a ready made implementation for brevity - [`_.zipObject()` from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#zipObject). However, it can be custom changed or entirely custom built, if needed.

With that a call would look like

```
wrap(someFn, "b", [ 'bar' ]
```

which will produce a function that can be called like

```
wrappedFn("hello", () => "some callback")
```

which would in turn call

```
someFn("b", [ 'bar' ], () => "some callback")
```

```js
const toObj = (keys, values) =>
  keys.length === 0
    ? null
    : _.zipObject(keys, values); 

function wrap(fn, name, keys) {
  return function(...args) {
    const callback = args.pop();
    const obj = toObj(keys, args);

    return fn.call(this, name, obj, callback);
  }
}

function someFn(name, obj, callback) {
  console.log(`name: '${name}'; obj: '${JSON.stringify(obj)}', callback: '${callback}'`);
}
const wrappedFn = wrap(someFn, "b", [ 'bar' ]);

wrappedFn("hello", () => "some callback");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Two notable things:

- the number of keys and values is not verified. If that is required, it needs to be handled
- the `length` property of the wrapped function will report zero, as that is how the rest syntax for parameters is defined to work. This means that examining it to find the number of parameters before calling will be unreliable

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach's core feature would be making use of a single, argument-handling, `this`-context aware function and [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)ing,

- firstly with a bound [`thisArg` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#thisarg),
- secondly with additionally [pre-bound parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#arg1) for the **socket name**, and the **array of expected parameter names**.

The actual parameters are getting fetched by the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#syntax) syntax.

The expected callback function could be [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)ped from the `args` array, which mutates the latter and leaves just the remaining parameter-values which need to be passed as values of a payload-like object where the object's keys are configured by the pre-bound `paramNames` array.

The `payload` gets created via a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping task which creates an array of key-value pairs which then gets passed to [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

The actual creation from a parameter configuration and the assignment of each created method to a target object can be achieved by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)ing the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of such a `config` object.

```js
function forwardWithBoundContextAndParamsConfig(
  socketName, paramNames, ...args
) {
  const callback =
    // ... ... ?? always assure at least a callback.
    args.pop() ?? (_ => _);

  const payload = (paramNames.length === 0)
    ? null
    : Object.fromEntries(
        paramNames.map((key, idx) => [key, args[idx] ])
      );

  // - forwarding upon the correct context
  //   and with the correct parameter data
  //   derieved from the bound configuration.
  return this.foo(socketName, payload, callback);
}

const methodConfig = {
  A: { socketName: 'a', paramNames: [] },
  B: { socketName: 'b', paramNames: ['bar'] },
  C: { socketName: 'c', paramNames: ['baz', 'qux'] },
};

class SocketTest {
  foo(socketName, payload, callback) {
    console.log({ socketName, payload, callback });
  }
}
Object
  .entries(methodConfig)
  .reduce((target, [methodName, { socketName, paramNames }]) => {

    target[methodName] = forwardWithBoundContextAndParamsConfig
      .bind(SocketTest.prototype, socketName, paramNames);

    return target;

  }, SocketTest.prototype);

console.log({
  SocketTest,
  'SocketTest.prototype': SocketTest.prototype,
});
const socketTest = new SocketTest;

socketTest.A();
socketTest.A(function callBack_A() {});

socketTest.B('quick', function callBack_B() {});
socketTest.C('brown', 'fox', function callBack_C() {});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```